# How to write a macro that inserts n blank rows in between every filled row? (where n is 2 or more)

Tags: vba, excel

(a) why does my code insert 3 row in between the filled rows instead of just inserting 1? 
(b) How do I modify the code to insert just 1 row, or for that matter 5 rows in between the filled rows?

Before running the code; the green outline shows my selection

[image]

After running the code

[image]

**Code**

```
Public Sub Insertrows()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyCell As Range

Set MyRange = Selection

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    If Not IsEmpty(MyCell) Then
        MyCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Your range (`MyRange`) has 30 cells, of which 9 appear to be not empty.  So you would expect your code to insert 9 rows, 3 after each current row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you're iterating through ALL cells of selected range, so: A1, A2,..., A10 and then B1, B2,... B10, and you hit not empty cells more than once in any row

use

```
For Each MyCell In MyRange.Columns(1).Cells
```

Comment: @user91820, if this solved your question, you may want to mark answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. thank you!

Comment: @user91820, any chance to get feedback from you?